# How do i create an RTC Baseline on a component in a stream using scm.exe?

Tags: automation, version-control, rational-team-concert

After building software from files from an RTC stream, I want to create a baseline of the component as a record of the state of the files.

It needs to be automated, hence the use of SCM.

I want to create it in a single step if I can, i.e, not create baseline on the component in a workspace, then deliver it.

I can create a baseline on a component in a workspace using:
`scm.exe create baseline -r Repository -u username -P password "workspace" "Baseline name" "Component name"`

Alternatively, how can I automatically deliver the baseline in the workspace above, or should I be using snapshots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of creating a baseline in a single step.

If you can create it in a dedicate workspace with, as a default flow target, the right stream, you should be able to call [`scm deliver`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/elm/7.0.3?topic=scm-deliver) ([examples](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/elm/7.0.3?topic=scm-deliver-example)), as [mentioned here](https://deliver:%20scm%20deliver%20-r%20%3Crepo%3E%20-s%20%3Csource_stream%3E%20-t%20%3Ctarget_stream%3E%20-b%20%3Cbaseline_uuid_or_name%3E):

```
 scm deliver: scm deliver -r <repo> -s <source_stream> -t <target_stream> -b <baseline_uuid_or_name>
```

Or [simply](https://deliver:%20scm%20deliver%20-r%20%3Crepo%3E%20-s%20%3Csource_stream%3E%20-t%20%3Ctarget_stream%3E%20-b%20%3Cbaseline_uuid_or_name%3E):

```
scm deliver -C <component>
```

Since it would deliver all changesets and baselines for that component.

Comment: That worked. I also had to add -s "Component"

Comment: @FrinkTheBrave Great, well done!